# Restore index and append zeros after subtracting dataframe values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am calculating the difference of a dataframe values at different lags.
Following dataframe is my input

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4],[5,6],[7,8]], columns=list('AB'))
```

To compute the difference between last three rows and first three rows, I am doing the following.

```
df2=df.iloc[1:,:]

df3=df.iloc[:-1,:] 

df_out=pd.DataFrame(df2.values-df3.values,index=df2.index)
```

The calculation is as expected but I want to retain the index 0 with zeros in that row.

```
df_expected_out=pd.DataFrame([[0,0], [2,2],[2,2],[2,2]], columns=list('AB'))
```

Please suggest the way forward.Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by original index:

```
df_out=pd.DataFrame(df2.values-df3.values,index=df2.index).reindex(df.index, fill_value=0)
print (df_out)
   0  1
0  0  0
1  2  2
2  2  2
3  2  2
```

Another solution:

```
df_out= df.diff().fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Or append first zero row to arrays:

```
a1 = np.zeros((1, len(df.columns)), dtype=int)
arr = np.append(a1, df2.values, axis=0) - np.append(a1, df3.values, axis=0)
df_out = pd.DataFrame(arr, index=df.index)
print (df_out)
   0  1
0  0  0
1  2  2
2  2  2
3  2  2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) function

```
(df - df.shift()).fillna(0)
Out[9]: 
     A    B
0  0.0  0.0
1  2.0  2.0
2  2.0  2.0
3  2.0  2.0
```